# Why is Django only showing some of my translations

Tags: django, internationalization, django-cms

I've got a site with translation strings in both the HTML templates and the `views.py`, `forms.py` and `models.py` files. Django has created the `django.po` file for my second language, and I have entered most of the translations. However, only translations in my .html and view.py files are showing up on the site. the others are being ignored it seems (models.py, forms.py - both defaulting to English)

What's going on?

I've obviously compiled my `django.mo` file and that's working - otherwise a lot of template strings wouldn't be translated - so why is it ignoring my `models.py` translations. Both in the admin site and the front end.

One thought is that there may be an error in the `django.mo` file that causes it to break. Is there any way to test a `django.mo` file for errors? Would it work at all if there was an error?

My project also has Django-cms installed, which could be causing some conflict?

Thanks for any light shed.

Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Make sure you are always using `ugettext_lazy` (not `ugettext`) in model and form definitions

2.Remove possible [`fuzzy` tags](http://blog.e-shell.org/124) in the .mo files.

Comment: briefly - what's the difference between _lazy and not _lazy then? This made it work...

Comment: The `_lazy` version translates EVERYTIME the string is accessed, the normal version only once the code is run, which happens for forms and modules only on django's startup ONCE!