# Some translations are missing on Production server but showing up on DEV

Tags: django, translation, gettext, django-cms

Like I said in the topic title, there's some translations missing on PROD (but not on DEV!).

I've double validate that the translations are on the server.

I've check for any "fuzzy" marks in the .po and .mo files. There's not.

I've removed all "ugettext_lazy" I could found. Replaced by "ugettext"

I've run the makemessages and compilemessages on the server

I've clean the cache

I've restarted the process using supervisor and even restart the server (just in case)

And I always have the same problem. does anyone have an idea ?

Thread I've followed:

[Why is Django only showing some of my translations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165799/why-is-django-only-showing-some-of-my-translations)

[gettext translation not working on production system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102478/django-gettext-translation-not-working-on-production-system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I didn't found the real problem, but I did a fresh release of the same code and it worked. Maybe something goes wrong in the first release.